# 3 questions over the function $f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{1+x_0+x_1+x_2}(x_0+x_1,x_1+x_2,x_2+x_0).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

Let $D=\{(x_0,x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^3|\ 1+x_0+x_1+x_2 =0\}$ the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ passing for the points $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$, $(0,0,-1)$ and let $E=\mathbb{R}^3-D$ its complement. Note that $E$ is a open set and is the union of two semispaces (separated for the plane $D$).  Let
$$f:E\to\mathbb{R}^3\ ,\ (x_0,x_1,x_2)\mapsto f(x_0,x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{1+x_0+x_1+x_2}(x_0+x_1,x_1+x_2,x_2+x_0).$$

1. Show that for all  $\vec{x}\in E$, $Df(\vec{x})$ is of maximal rank. (i.e no have critic points).
2. Show that $f$ is injective.
3. Characterized the images $f(E)$ how union of two semispaces separated for some plane.

Thanks for your help.

Next my advances:

1. For $(x_0,x_1,x_2)\in E$,  I have that $$Df(x_0,x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{(1+x_0+x_1+x_2)^2}\left(
     \begin{array}{ccc}
        1+x_2& 1+x_2 &-x_0-x_1  \\
       -x_1-x_2 &1+x_0  &1+x_0  \\
        1+x_1& -x_0-x_2& 1+x_1 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)$$ but how show that $Df(x_0,x_1,x_2)\neq 0$?
2. For show that $f$ is injective it suffices to show that the determinant of $Df(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ is distinct of zero?
3. I not have idea how to perform this characterization.

Comment: Yes thanks @Thomas Andrews.

Comment: You want more than that $Df\neq 0$, you want $Df$ invertible. Ideally, you'd show if the determinant of the non-constant part of the derivative is zero, then so is $1+x_0+x_1+x_2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I need for part 2?

Comment: No, for part (1), "max rank" here means $Df(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is invertible, not just non-zero.

Comment: To show that $Df$ has maximal rank everywhere, just compute its determinant and show that it never vanishes. As already noted, this is not enough to show that $f$ is injective. Perhaps it helps if you rewrite $f$ as $(1 - \frac{1+x_2}{1+x_0+x_1+x_2} , \dots)$.

Comment: As to part 3, try this. Let $D_c = \{x_0+x_1+x_2 = c\}$. Show that for all $c \ne -1$ the function $f$ maps $D_c$ to some $D_d$ and that it is one to one and onto there. This is a calculation with linear maps, since the denominator is constant on each $D_c$. This will also characterize the image $f(E)$: It is $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus D_{d^\ast}$ for a suitable $d^\ast$.

Comment: @HansEngler, I showed that $f(D_c)=D_{\frac{2c}{1+c}}$  but I not can find the suitable number $d^{\ast}$... some help?

Comment: $\displaystyle f(E)=f(\mathbb{R}^3-D)=f\left(\bigcup_{\substack{c\in\mathbb{R}\\c\neq -1}}D_c\right)   =\bigcup_{\substack{c\in\mathbb{R}\\c\neq -1}}f(D_c)    = \bigcup_{\substack{c\in\mathbb{R}\\c\neq -1}}D_{\frac{2c}{1+c}}$ and how obtain that is equal to $\mathbb{R}^3-D_{d^{*}}$?

Comment: @HansEngler I showed that $f(E)=\mathbb{R}^3-D_2$. Thanks you so much!!